# Web-scraping bountied questions from Stack Exchange sites

Tags: python, time-limit-exceeded, web-scraping, stackexchange

I recently built my first web scraper in python, and decided to use SO and SE as test websites.

#### Code

```
# import selenium
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
from google.colab import output

# clear output
output.clear()

bounties = []
question_link = []

site = 1

while True:
  # Some site no.'s are missing
  page = 1
  try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver", options = chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://stackexchange.com/sites")
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    results = soup.find(id = f"gv-site-{site}")
    site_link = str(results.find_all("a", class_ = "btn float-right"))

    _, site_link = site_link.split('href="')
    site_link, _ = site_link.split('">Visit Site')

    break_ = False
    while True:
      try:
        driver.get(f"{site_link}/questions?tab=bounties&page={page}")
        content_ = driver.page_source
        soup_ = BeautifulSoup(content_)
        results_ = soup_.find(id = "questions")

        questions = results_.find_all("div", class_ = "s-post-summary js-post-summary")
        for question in questions:
          # output html code
          #print(question.prettify(), end = "\n"*2)
          link = str(question.find("a", class_ = "s-link"))
          link = link[24:]
          link, title = link.split('">')
          link = site_link + link
          #print(link)

          bounty = "".join(re.findall(r"\d+", str(question.find("div", class_ = "s-post-summary--stats-item has-bounty"))))
          #print(question.find("div", class_ = "s-post-summary--stats-item has-bounty"))
          bounty = int(bounty[:len(bounty) // 2])
          if bounty == 500:
            bounties.append(bounty)
            question_link.append(link)
          # clear output
          output.clear()
          print(bounties)
          print(question_link)

      except Exception as e:
        # get line of error
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        #print(f"{e} - Line {exc_tb.tb_lineno}")
        break_ = True

      page += 1
      site += 1

      if break_: break

  except Exception as e:
    # get line of error
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    #print(f"{e} - Line {exc_tb.tb_lineno}")
    site += 1
    pass
  
  print(bounties)
  print(question_link)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Link":question_link, "Bounty":bounties})
print(df)
```

#### Problem+Disclaimer

This code runs through **all** the possible bounties in *all* sites in SE and SO, so it will take a while. But I'm quite sure I can optimise this code in some way. Note, trying to run this program and get the final total output will take surely hours (for me it's still running!), so maybe you can just try to see if it speeds up in a way.

Also I'm not sure why the `output.clear()` that I used doesn't work consistently. Why so? So I use another way to clear output? Note that the purpose of using this is to ensure there is only one output so it doesn't get messy. But after the `bounties` gets to a length of 4, it stops clearing the output.

Comment: Why are you scraping instead of using [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions)?

Comment: @200_success Thanks! But it's a **test**, I'm not actually going to use this site for running